# Can we add 2 event handlers in nagios service definition

Tags: nagios

Suppose we have a service definition in nagios as:

```
define service{
    host_name           some host
    service_description xxx
    max_check_attempts      4
    event_handler       restart-XXX
    ...
    }
```

Now my question is can we add 2 event_handlers say `event_handler1` and `event_handler2` this should look something like:

```
event_handler1      restart-XXX
    event_handler2      restart-YYY
    ...
        }
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this two different ways:

1. You can register a global event handler, and then a per service/host event handler.

   In your command definition:
       define command{
           command_name    global_event_handler
           command_line    /path/to/script $ARGUMENTS$
       }

   ```
   define command{
       command_name    host_event_handler
       command_line    /path/to/script2 $ARGUMENTS$
   }
   ```

   Then, in main nagios configuration:

   ```
   global_host_event_handler=global_event_handler
   ```

   And in your host definition:

   ```
   define host{
       name            some_host
       address         127.1.2.3
       event_handler   host_event_handler
   }
   ```
2. You can write a script that will execute both, and set that as the event handler.

   In your command definition:

   ```
   define command{
       command_name    host_event_handler
       command_line    /path/to/script $ARGUMENTS$
   }
   ```

   In your host definition:

   ```
   define host{
       name            some_host
       address         127.1.2.3
       event_handler   host_event_handler
   }
   ```

   Then, in /path/to/script:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   /path/to/script1
   /path/to/script2
   ```

Hope this helps!